# Loading JS in asset pipeline

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I have just updated my site to use a jQuery plugin `jquery.raty.min.js`

The plugin allows the user to choose jQuery style rating stars when completing a review.

http://www.wbotelhos.com/raty/

Everything works fine on localhost, but when I deploy to "heroku" I receive an error that stops me from even loading the home page! See error below:

```
 ActionView::Template::Error ('twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.
   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)):
6:     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
7:     <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
8:     <![endif]-->    
9:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
10:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
11:     <%= include_gon %>
12:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>    
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4184194920936324767_38840920'
```

On localhost everything works fine without adding a require line for raty ie `//= require jquery.raty.min` but on "heroku" the plugin doesn't load at all. To fix it I added the require line, but then I started receiving the above error for every page on the site.

EDIT:

My application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require_tree .
```

It doesn't seem to matter where I put the include for `jquery.raty.min`.  It always breaks :)

UPDATE:

I am actually using https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and in order to fix this I needed to add to my application.css:

```
*= bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to include twitter-bootstrap in your application css

```
*= require 'twitter/bootstrap'
```

Comment: but what about your application.css not the JS

Answer (score 0):

Adding `*= bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` in my application.css file did not fix a similar issue I was having with the twitter-boostrap-rails gem on heroku. You may need to set the following in your config/application.rb file:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I found this originally at:
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2012/02/heroku-and-rails-3-2-assetprecompile-error/

I also left `*= bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` in my application.css file as Abram suggests and all works will on Heroku now.

Answer (score 0):

try `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html